# Two replies with same References and In-Reply-To: one shows as reply to original message, the other not

Tags: gmail, mime-message

I have to messages with the same References and In-Reply-To values, one shows in Gmail as a reply to the original message the other not.  What headers should be used to get the message displayed as a reply in Gmail?

Message that shows as reply:

```
Delivered-To: tonny@deskdrive.com
From: Tonny Bruckers <tonny@deskdrive.biz>
To: Tonny Bruckers <tonny@deskdrive.com>
Subject: Re: t
Thread-Topic: t
Thread-Index: AQHaB9TkTkuWrb6IIkGCerWGlIh9ELBbm+qE
Date: Thu, 26 Oct 2023 06:29:45 +0000
Message-ID:
 <AS4P192MB17913E2BE6DB474BC32E2B22B2DDA@AS4P192MB1791.EURP192.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>
References:
 <CACKNNbzHEQBns0a-6w3wTbWmCNEEPS9F3JYL9k8Ws5W3eLERSg@mail.gmail.com>
In-Reply-To:
 <CACKNNbzHEQBns0a-6w3wTbWmCNEEPS9F3JYL9k8Ws5W3eLERSg@mail.gmail.com>
Accept-Language: nl-BE, en-US
Content-Language: nl-BE
X-MS-Has-Attach:
```

Message that does not show as reply:

```
Delivered-To: tonny@deskdrive.com
From: Tonny Bruckers <tonny@deskdrive.biz>
To: Tonny Bruckers <tonny@deskdrive.com>
Subject: Re: t
Thread-Topic: t
Thread-Index: AQHaB9TkTkuWrb6IIkGCerWGlIh9ELBbmp6d
Date: Thu, 26 Oct 2023 06:27:57 +0000
Message-ID:
 <AS4P192MB17915239CC3340326D8886B5B2DDA@AS4P192MB1791.EURP192.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>
References:
 <CACKNNbzHEQBns0a-6w3wTbWmCNEEPS9F3JYL9k8Ws5W3eLERSg@mail.gmail.com>
In-Reply-To:
 <CACKNNbzHEQBns0a-6w3wTbWmCNEEPS9F3JYL9k8Ws5W3eLERSg@mail.gmail.com>
```